# NetSuite Saved Search returning invalid expression when trying to Case/When for specific GL transactions

Tags: netsuite

So I have a Saved Search that is going through a bunch of payroll GL accounts and returning values for those specific accounts, all good.

But I need to grab some additional non-payroll accounts that are narrowed down by vendor (such as bank charges that the payroll company is passing through).

I've started with Formula(Text):

CASE {account} WHEN '12345 General Expenses : Bank Fees' AND {companyname} = 'Bank Example' Then ({amount}) ELSE = 0 END

Tried '0', instead of companyname have tried entityid, vendor.altname, and a myriad of different guesses. The companyname is the id given when I click Company Name for field help. Same if I change it to entityid. Copy and pastes from within NetSuite.

Receive the value of "ERROR: Invalid Expression" for the columns associated with the Case function.

Basically I want it to look through the account 12345, and if there is an amount present for vendor Bank Example, to return the amount.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a search case expression instead of simple case when evaluating an expression with multiple conditions.

```
CASE WHEN {account} = '12345 General Expenses : Bank Fees' AND {companyname} = 'Bank Example' THEN {amount} ELSE 0 END
```

You should also use `Formula (Currency)` or `Formula (Numeric)` when you expect a currency or numeric value to be returned from your formula.

Comment: Gotcha on the formula field being numeric instead of text.

I've reordered and updated but still receiving the same Error invalid expression:

CASE WHEN {account} = '12345 General Expenses : Bank Fees and Finance Charges' AND {companyname} = 'Bank Name, Inc.' THEN ({amount}) ELSE = 0 END

I've also tried changing {companyname} to {entityid} = "V0001 Bank Name, Inc.'

I don't know why this isn't letting me insert line breaks...

Comment: I missed a syntax error.  It should be `ELSE 0 END` NOT `ELSE = 0 END` at the end of the case statement.

Comment: Taking out the = got me to "Field Not Found" so fiddled some more and have it returning zeros. So progress! I think it's a matter of getting the field correct. As I can scroll through the search and what I'm looking for is there, it's just not taking it over to that column. Have tried Formula(Currency) and Formula (Numeric). 

I'll keep plugging away at it.

Comment: Here's a tip: try adding `{account}` and `{companyname}` as separate `Formula (text)` columns to verify what you get.  You can use the results from those columns to verify and validate the comparisons in your `CASE` statement.  EG: `{account}` may give you `'Bank Fees'` rather than `'12345 General Expenses : Bank Fees'`.